# ListBox binding not working in test configuration

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, listbox

I'm having trouble with binding a ListBox and I can't for the life of me figure out what's wrong. Most of the time it works fine, but in a special test configuration I have for my application it doesn't work and it's driving me crazy. I've literally stared at it for hours and tried all sorts of things. It's gotta be a binding issue, but I can't find it. There aren't any exceptions or binding errors being thrown that I can see.

The test configuration is identical to my debug configuration, but with an additional compilation symbol. It allows me to test the WPF application without running the entire software stack. It's an "offline mode" for all intents and purposes.

```
<ribbon:Ribbon Height="45">
<ribbon:Ribbon.ApplicationMenu>
    <ribbon:RibbonApplicationMenu Width="56">
        <ribbon:RibbonApplicationMenuItem Header="New Campaign" Command="{Binding Path=AddCampaign}" ImageSource="images\new.png"/>
        <ribbon:RibbonApplicationMenuItem Header="Save Campaigns" Command="{Binding Path=Save}" ImageSource="images\save.png" />
        <ribbon:RibbonApplicationMenuItem Header="Import Campaign" Command="{Binding Path=ImportCampaign}" ImageSource="images\campaign-import-128x128.png"/>
        <ribbon:RibbonApplicationMenuItem Header="Export Campaign" Command="{Binding Path=ExportCampaign}" ImageSource="images\campaign-export-128x128.png" />
        <ribbon:RibbonApplicationMenuItem Header="Terms of Use" Command="{Binding Path=Eula}" ImageSource="images\terms.png"/>
        <ribbon:RibbonApplicationMenuItem Header="Resources" Command="{Binding Path=Resources}" ImageSource="images\resource.jpg"/>
        <ribbon:RibbonApplicationMenuItem Header="About" Command="{Binding Path=About}" ImageSource="images\resource.jpg"/>
        <ribbon:RibbonApplicationMenu.AuxiliaryPaneContent>
            <StackPanel>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <Label Width="130" Content="Campaign"/>
                    <Label Width="60" Content="Duplicate"/>
                    <Label Width="50" Content="Delete"/>
                </StackPanel>
                <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Repository.Campaigns}" 
                            SelectedItem="{Binding Path=SelectedCampaign, Mode=TwoWay}" 
                            ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource ListBoxItemStyle}" 
                            Height="212" 
                            ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" 
                            ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden">
                    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                <Label Content="{Binding Path=Name}" Width="130" />
                                <Button Command="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ItemsControl}}, Path=DataContext.DuplicateCampaign}"
                                    CommandParameter="{Binding Path=Name}" Width="60">
                                    <Button.Template>
                                        <ControlTemplate>
                                            <Border HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" >
                                                <Image Source="/asdf;component/images/duplicate.png" Width="24" Height="24"/>
                                            </Border>
                                        </ControlTemplate>
                                    </Button.Template>
                                </Button>
                                <Button Command="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ItemsControl}}, Path=DataContext.RemoveCampaign}"
                                    CommandParameter="{Binding Path=Name}" Width="50">
                                    <Button.Template>
                                        <ControlTemplate>
                                            <Border HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" >
                                                <Image Source="/asdf;component/images/delete.png" Width="24" Height="24"/>
                                            </Border>
                                        </ControlTemplate>
                                    </Button.Template>
                                </Button>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                </ListBox>
                <Button Content="View Archived" 
                        Command="{Binding Path=ArchivedCampaigns}"></Button>
            </StackPanel>
        </ribbon:RibbonApplicationMenu.AuxiliaryPaneContent>
        <ribbon:RibbonApplicationMenu.FooterPaneContent>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Right">
                <ribbon:RibbonButton Label="LOGOUT" Command="{Binding Path=Logout}" />
                <ribbon:RibbonButton Label="EXIT" Command="{Binding Path=Exit}" />
            </StackPanel>
        </ribbon:RibbonApplicationMenu.FooterPaneContent>
    </ribbon:RibbonApplicationMenu>
</ribbon:Ribbon.ApplicationMenu>
```

Here's my login method where the window is created and the DataContext is bound. UITEST is my offline mode configuration.

```
private void Login()
{
    MainVM = new ViewModel.MainWindowVM();
    _mainWindow = new RibbonMainWindow
    {
        DataContext = MainVM
    };

    //Prompt user for login.
#if UITEST
    _loggedIn = true;
    MainVM.LoadData();
#else
    var loginWindow = new Login();
    var login = new ViewModel.LoginVM();
    loginWindow.DataContext = login;
    loginWindow.ShowDialog();
    if (loginWindow.DialogResult != null) _loggedIn = loginWindow.DialogResult.Value;
#endif

    if (_loggedIn && MainVM.Loaded)
    {
        _mainWindow.ShowDialog();
    }
}
```

Edit: As near as I can guess, it might be due to using the legacy RibbonControlsLibrary from the pre .NET 4.5 days. I retargeted the software to .NET 4.6.1 last year so I switched to the Ribbon built-in to .NET and now it works oddly enough. If I try to  mess with anything else in the window it just seems to break again. Like if I try to strongly-type the DataContext in the window.

Comment: Uhhh, could you maybe explain the "special test configuration" that isn't working?!

Comment: Oh, sorry. It's identical to my debug configuration, but with an additional compilation symbol. It allows me to test the WPF application without running the entire software stack. It's an "offline mode" for all intents and purposes.

Comment: My first guess is that DataContext is not being set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As near as I can guess, it might be due to using the legacy RibbonControlsLibrary from the pre .NET 4.5 days. I retargeted the software to .NET 4.6.1 last year so I switched to the Ribbon built-in to .NET and now it works oddly enough. If I try to mess with anything else in the window it just seems to break again. Like if I try to strongly-type the DataContext in the window.